# How can I overlay a colour and a pattern?

Tags: microsoft-excel

Is there any way I can add a pattern onto a colored cell through conditional formatting such that the color of the cell remains visible?

I am trying to do a sort of Gantt chart, where the different colours represent different people:

[image: 5]

When I activate a cell I want to highlight the selected row and column with a pattern. I have managed to create that functionality, however, when a pattern shows, the colour disappears.

In below I move the cursor one cell up. The corresponding row gets a pattern, but the red colour disappears. If I move the cursor one cell up and to the left, the same happens with the yellow colour.

[image: 1] [image: 2] [image: 3]

I've tried below VBA code, and the result is the same: when the pattern shows, the colour disappears.

```vb
LR = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    
Set PatternRng = Range("A6" & ":" & "GM" & Sheets("Source").Range("I1").Value)
PatternRng.Interior.Pattern = xlPatternNone

If ((ActiveCell.Row >= 7) And (ActiveCell.column <= 194) And (ActiveCell.Row <= LR)) Then
    If (ActiveCell.column > 1) Then
       Set PatternRng = Range("A6:A" & LR).Offset(, ActiveCell.column - 1)
       PatternRng.Interior.Pattern = xlPatternGray25
       PatternRng.Interior.PatternColor = RGB(191, 191, 191)
    End If
        
    Set PatternRng = Range("A6:GM6").Offset(ActiveCell.Row - 6, 0)
    PatternRng.Interior.Pattern = xlPatternGray25
    PatternRng.Interior.PatternColor = RGB(191, 191, 191)
        
    Sheets("Source").Range("I2").Value = (ActiveCell.column - 1)
    Sheets("Source").Range("I3").Value = (ActiveCell.Row - 6)
End If
```

Comment: The cells have in your screencaps have no values, which conditional formatting kind of depends on. It would also be useful to know what the conditions for any given colour is. What is your desired goal here?

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad Sorry, I have updated my question and added another picture so it is easier to understand what I want to achive.

Comment: @cha28 Hi and welcome to superuser! Have you done [some research on how to highlight a row/column when a cell is selected](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask)? Even if you only found some solutions which you did not understand, or did not work for you it's useful to include that in your question. Others then know what you've looked into and can answer accordingly.

Comment: @SaaruLindestøkke Yes, and I have also tried with the VBA code and got it to work, exept that the color disaper. So I ran out och ideas.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, and for showing what you've tried so far, much appreciated! I'm no VBA expert, but what I think you should do is try to set the pattern colour to the colour of the cell that is highlighted. So in VBA you would [first read the colour of the highlighted cell](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.interior.color) and then set the [pattern colour](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.interior.patterncolor) to the same value.

Comment: @SaaruLindestøkke If I do it the VBA way, do you know a more efficient way then to loop thrugh all cells? Because x-axis has every day for six month and y-axis is dynamic but will be atleast 30 rows.

Comment: Best way to start is to do a websearch on related terms, like: "highlight row column selected cell excel" or something like that. From there on you'll probably find VBA code that you can adapt for your own situation. If you find something, but don't know how to apply it, please [edit] your question to indicate where you get stuck.